# not ignore comments in Lex and YACC

Tags: compiler-errors, yacc, lex

I've done a source to source compiler in Lex and YACC and I'm trying to save the line comments of the source file into the destination file. 
The comment line can be specified just with the "#" symbol. 
There are only single-line comments.

I created the rule in the parser named Y_COMMENT.
The problem is in the LEX...probably into the regular expression. 
Actually, the comments are caught with this rule:

```
"#".*  {}
```

I modified the rule into:

```
"#".*/\n { 
      current_line_no = line_no;
      current_line = yytext;
      yyval.p = (char*) copy_str(yytext+1,1);
      return (Y_COMMENT);
      }
```

The parser works just for the first comment line. After that, it give me an error about "unrecognized line code"

Comment: forward slash(/) after .* is not needed

Comment: Thank you! It works for the first comment line, but not for the second (sight!). Now, the error is related to the space after the termination of the comment (possible space between the last character and the line termination). Probably, the regular expression is too vague...

Comment: There is far too little information here to provide a good answer. A [mre] would be ideal, but at a minimum you should specify what part of your code produces the "unrecognized line code" error, which cannot be produced spontaneously by either flex or yacc/bison generated code.

Comment: yes, sorry....but I solved the problem in another way.. :-) thank you so much for the help!